# How do I remove illegal characters in a subdomain?

Tags: java, replace, subdomain, illegal-characters

I'm using Java 6.  Using an Amazon AWS library, I'm dynamically creating domains.  However, I'm looking for a function that can strip out illegal characters from a subdomain.  E.g. if my function were about to create

```
dave'ssite.mydomain.com
```

I would like to pass the string "dave'ssite" to some function, which would strip out the apostrophe, or whatever other illegal characters lurked in the subdomain.

How do I do taht?  THe more specific quesiton is, how do I identify what the illegal subdomain characters are?

Answer (score 1):

Subdomains are same as Domains, so most likely the allowed characters are `A-Z a-z 0-9 and -`.  There fore you can use Regex.

```
...
String s = "dave's-site.mydomain.com";

//prints daves-sitemydomaincom
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\-]","")); 
...
```

Comment: This answer is too simple. First of all, parts of domain names are not allowed to start with a hyphen and to validate a domain name part, the length is also relevant. Considering IDNs, restricting the allowed characters to a-z is wrong.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Valid point. Length, hyphen not at start or end also need to be validated.

Comment: Bala, before I accept, can you update your answer to reflect the changes jarnbjo is talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some I made for a game. Its basically the same thing except I used it for removing invalid characters from a username.

```
char[] validChars = {a, b, c, d, etc...};//Put all valid characters in this array, so for subdomains put all letters and numbers
public static String cleanString(String text){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for(int i = 0;i < text.length();i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < validCharslength; j++) {
            if (validChars[j] == text.charAt(i)) {
                sb.append(text.charAt(i));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

As said my the comment in the code, the char array contains all the valid characters and anything else will be removed. Keep in mind that his is a return method.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on here looking for a c# solution to the same problem and well here it is. Look how elegant c# LINQ makes this ;)

```
if (model.UserName.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit) && !model.UserName.StartsWith("-")) 
{ 
    //oh yeah, valid subdomain     
}
```

Not sure what the spec says about length though.